# Solving an inequality for minimum value

Tags: python, language-agnostic, equation, linear-programming, inequality

I'm working on a programming problem which boils down to a set of an equation and inequality:

```
x[0]*a[0] + x[1]*a[1] + ... x[n]*a[n] >= D
x[0]*b[0] + x[1]*b[1] + ... x[n]*b[n] =  C
```

I want to solve for the values of `X` that will give the absolute minimum of `C`, given the input `D` and lists and `A` and `B` consisting of `a[0 - n]` and `b[0 - n ]`.

I'm doing the problem at the moment in Python, but the problem in general is language-agnostic.

CLARIFICATION UPDATE: the coefficients `x[0 - n]` are restricted to the set of non-negative integers.

Comment: On a casual glance, it looks like this problem would have multiple solutions. Can you give some actual data to look at?

Comment: Have x[0] ... x[n] to be greater than or equal to zero?

Comment: Yes, they do.  Thanks for the clarifying question.

Comment: Hmm, then I would also stick with linear programming...

Comment: INTEGERS! Then it is an integer programming problem (much more difficult), branch&bound and all the like will do.

Comment: PS - I don't think (hope) you'll find folks here giving you a complete answer. It's too much of a textbook problem for that... ;)

Comment: @Barry:
I wasn't looking for the complete answer, no.  Just pointers as to what sort of work had been done in the area.

Answer (score 11):

This looks like a [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem. The [Simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) normally gives good results. It basically walks the boundaries of the subspace delimited by the inequalities, looking for the optimum.

Think of it visually: each inequality denotes a half-space, a plane in n-dimensional space that you have to be on the right side of. Your utility function is what you're trying to optimize. If the space is closed, the optimum is going to be at one of the apexes of the closed space; if it's open, it's possible that the optimum is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Integer_unknowns) entry on linear programming. The integer programming section is what you're searching for (the constraint of the x[i] being integers is not an easy one).

Search python libraries for branch&bound, branch&cut and the like (I don't think they have been implemented in scipy yet).

Other interesting links:

- [GNU Linear Programming Kit](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/)
- [IBM article on GLPK](http://www-128.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-glpk1/)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Matlab or Mathematica or look at code from [Numerical Recipes in C](http://www.nrbook.com/a/bookcpdf.php) for ideas on how to implement minimization functions. The link provided is to the 1992 version of the book.  Newer versions are available at Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

This [company](http://www.lindo.com/) has a tool to do that sort of thing.